# Ideal tetrahedron maximum volume

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry

I want to that any tetrahedron in $\Bbb{H}^3$ can be transformed into a tetrahedron that has $0, 1, \infty, z$ as vertices. Also I need to show that the above defined tetrahedron has maximum volume if $z=e^{\frac{2\pi i}{6}}$ and I need to find the maximum volume. Please provide some reference or give me some hints. I have a very limited exposure to hyperbolic geometry.

Comment: Please also refer some good undergraduate text of three dimensional hyperbolic geometry.

Comment: First of all, what do you mean by “0, 1, ∞, z”?  I'm not aware of a convention that uses complex scalars as coordinates in a 3space.

Comment: The upper half space model of three dimensional hyperbolic geometry is the complex plane plus the point at infinity and the region above the complex plane in Euclidean three space.

Comment: Ah. It's good to specify which model you mean.

Comment: Why do you need to find the maximal volume? I don't think this is an easy exercise, or there is a very simple way to see it, especially if you are new to hyperbolic geometry. You can look at chapter 7 of Thurstons notes.